# Troubles with cudaMemcpyToSymbol

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm trying to copy to constant memory. But I can not because of my misunderstanding of usage of cudaMemcpyToSymbol function. I'm trying to follow [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gf268fa2004636b6926fdcd3189152a14.html)

Here is some code

```
__device__ __constant__ double var1;
__device__ __constant__ int var2;

int main(){

   //... some code here...

   double var1ToCopy = 10.1;
   int var2ToCopy = 1; 

   void * p1 = &var1ToCopy; 
   void * p2 = &var2ToCopy;

   cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol((void*)&var1,p1,sizeof(double),0,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess){
      return -1;
   }

   cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol((void*)&var2,p2,sizeof(int),0,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess){
      return -1;
   }


   //... and some code here...
}
```

I know it is a very dumb question, but I have spent several hours googling an answer and did not had any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the ampersand on the symbol name.  A symbol is not the same as a pointer or a variable.

Instead of this:

```
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol((void*)&var1,p1,sizeof(double),0,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Do this:

```
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(var1,&var1ToCopy,sizeof(double));
```

I've also simplified the above call based on the fact that some of the parameters have defaults as indicated in [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g2a229a704ade54887f7784e2e2dbd895).

Here's a fully worked example around a modfied version of your code (requires cc2.0+ GPU):

```
$ cat t626.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ __constant__ double var1;
__device__ __constant__ int var2;

__global__ void kernel(){

  printf("%f\n", var1);
  printf("%d\n", var2);
}


int main(){


   double var1ToCopy = 10.1;
   int var2ToCopy = 1;
   cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(var1,&var1ToCopy,sizeof(double));
   if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {printf("fail1\n"); return 1;}

   cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(var2,&var2ToCopy,sizeof(int));
   if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {printf("fail2\n"); return 1;}
   kernel<<<1,1>>>();
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   return 0;

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t626 t626.cu
$ ./t626
10.100000
1
$
```

Comment: Clear and great answer. Thank you! By the way I've tried `cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(var1,&var1ToCopy,sizeof(double));` But Visual Studio underlines it with red line. It confused me, so I didn't try to compile project. Now i think it's a good practice sometimes not to listen that VS says.

Comment: Agreed. CUDA C/C++ is not pure C/C++, and to a first order approximation, in this context, Intellisense is a C/C++ syntax checker.  As such, it can be problematic with CUDA. This particular issue (underlining of a library function call) may be something you can work around with inclusion of certain header files, but in the general case it's my understanding that Intellisense will not always be completely happy with CUDA code, therefore I personally wouldn't spend much time worrying about the intellisense red underlines, if the code compiles and runs correctly. Others may have a different view.