# Problems in CUDA function cudaMemcpyToSymbol()

Tags: cuda

I'm transporting data to specific CUDA symbol, my CUDA version is 10.1, GPU is Tesla K80. I compiled the code on VS2017, code generated by compute_35 & sm35. When I wrote my code like this,

```
<.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
__device__ __constant__ float scoreRatio;

<.cpp>
const float ScoreRatio;
cudaErr=cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&scoreRatio,&ScoreRatio,sizeof(ScoreRatio));
printf("%d: %s.\n",cudaErr,cudaGetErorString(cudaErr));
```

it compiled well but got `cudaErrInvalidSymbol` when I run the program,

```
13: Invalid device symbol
```

If I modified my code like this,

```
<.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
__device__ __constant__ float scoreRatio;

<.cpp>
const float ScoreRatio;
cudaErr=cudaMemcpyToSymbol(scoreRatio,&ScoreRatio,sizeof(ScoreRatio));
```

then the compile would fail due to incompatible parameter type as the first parameter is FLOAT while function asks VOID*, here I found the function definition in cuda_runtime_api.h,

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyToSymbol(const void *symbol, const void *src, size_t count, size_t offset __dv(0), enum cudaMemcpyKind kind __dv(cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Could anyone please give some advice, much appreciated.

Comment: what is `__contant__` ?  I suggest you show the actual, complete code you are compiling, along with the actual compile error output from VS

Comment: Sorry to make this silly mistake and appreciate your reply, I just edit my question. It seems most cases like this can be solved by change &scoreRatio to scoreRatio, but its obviously cannot fit the parameter type request of cudaMemcpyToSymbol() definition.

Comment: you can't reference a variable tagged with `__device__` or `__constant__` in a .cpp file.  An ordinary host C++ compiler doesn't know what that is.  You need to put all this in a .cu file, and let the nvcc compiler driver handle it.

Comment: Thank you. Before CUDA 4.0, reference a __decive__ variable in .cpp file seems feasible because function cudaMemcpyToSymbol() accepts string naming a variable as the first parameter. Since this rule has been deprecated and removed, how could i transfer value from host to device in .cpp? Or it's simply impossible?

Comment: create a wrapper function in the .cu file where the `__device__` or `__constant__` variable is defined.  The wrapper function takes a parameter that is the data to be stored in the `__device__` or `__constant__` variable and calls `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`. In your .cpp file where you would like to update the `__device__` or `__constant__` variable, call the wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
__device__ __constant__ float scoreRatio;

<.cpp>
const float ScoreRatio;
cudaErr=cudaMemcpyToSymbol(&scoreRatio,&ScoreRatio,sizeof(ScoreRatio));
printf("%d: %s.\n",cudaErr,cudaGetErorString(cudaErr));
```

is illegal/wrong in two ways. You must use nvcc to compile the code using a device code aware trajectory, and the first argument of the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` call is incorrect. If you simply rename your `.cpp` source file to have a `.cu` file extension and change the contents so that it looks like this:

```
<.cu>
#include <.h>
....
const float ScoreRatio;
cudaErr=cudaMemcpyToSymbol(scoreRatio, &ScoreRatio, sizeof(ScoreRatio));
printf("%d: %s.\n", cudaErr, cudaGetErorString(cudaErr));
```

it will both compile and run correctly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672635/681865) for an explanation of why it is necessary to change the first argument of the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` call.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Actually i am updating code which written in CUDA 4.0 before to CUDA 10.1. It's quite a big program, so if I just simply change .cpp to .cu, more errors would come out. Anyway, I am working on it and thank you again.